# How to fix default values from a dictionary Pythonically?

Tags: python

I am parsing JSON requests using the JSON library which parses into python dictionary. As the requests are user-generated, I need to fix default values for parameters that have not been supplied. Other languages have stuff like ternary operators which make sense for repetitive applications. But the code below needs 4 lines per parameter.

```
if "search_term" in request.keys():
    search_term=request['search_term']
else:
    search_term=""
if "start" in request.keys():
    start=request['start']
else:
    start=0
if "rows" in request.keys():
    rows=request['rows']
else:
    rows=1000000
```

Is there a Pythonic way to reduce the lines of code or make it more readable?

---

**Edit**: Both the (top) answers are equally useful. I used both in different circumstances

Comment: Since no one else has pointed this out yet, the line: **if "rows" in request.keys():** is equivalent to the simpler: **if "rows" in request:**.

Comment: We are left to wonder if the (two) top answers are the same now as they were in 2011.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [`dict.update`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method on a copy of the defaults:

```
defaults = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)

result = dict(defaults)  # Copy the defaults
result.update(request)  # Update with your values
```

This allows you to keep `defaults` as a class attribute or module global variable, which you probably want to do.

You can also combine the last two lines into:

```
result = dict(defaults, **request)
```

For another solution, see [Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688453/how-to-fix-default-values-from-a-dictionary-pythonically/7688516#7688516).

Comment: I like this as an alternative to dict.get(), because it allows you to specify all of your default values on one line. This may be useful if your defaults are likely to change in the future - then you don't have to hunt through a lot of `if` statements to find where they are declared.

Comment: +1 - provides one central place to manage your defaults and highly maintainable. Good answer!

Comment: +1. This is an excellent solution.  I must stress that with this method must be used with a copy of `defaults`, otherwise `defaults` get modified.  Also, the logic cannot be flipped.  Doing `request.update(defaults)` would overwrite the request with default values.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the dictionary method `get`, whose second argument is the default value to return if no value exists in the dictionary.

```
start = request.get('start', 0)
```

Comment: +1 This method is readable and simple to understand. I prefer it when there aren't too many values with defaults.

Answer (score 2):

Python dictionaries have a `get()` function that takes a default parameter (you can check that [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)). So you can do something like:

```
params.get('search_term', '')
params.get('some_other_field', 0)
```

and so on.

EDIT:: You probably want to go with the `update` solution from Petr above.

Answer (score 2):

If you're lucky enough to use Python 3.3+, you can use [`collections.ChainMap`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections#chainmap-objects):

```
from collections import ChainMap

defaults = {'color': 'red', 'taste': 'sweet'}
request = {'taste': 'sour', 'size': 'small'}

result = ChainMap(request, defaults)

print(result['taste'])  # sour  -- overridden
print(result['color'])  # red   -- from default
print(result['size'])   # small -- new value
```

Both the `defaults` and `request` dicts are “linked” to the ChainMap, not copied. Any changes to them will be reflected in `result`:

```
defaults['color'] = 'green'
print(result['color'])   # green

del result['taste']
print(result['taste'])  # sweet
```

To prevent this, you could convert a ChainMap to dict when you're done building it. This also helps if you need to deal with arrogant code that does `isinstance(result, dict)`:

```
print(dict(result))
# {'color': 'green', 'taste': 'sweet', 'size': 'small'}
```

Comment: Nice.  There's a useable 2.x implementation of ChainMap (spelled slightly differently) at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/305268/ as well (the link is in the 3.x docs but I thought it should go here too).

Comment: @torek True. It's probably not worth the bother in this particular case, though.