# How to set default value to all keys of a dict object in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I know you can use setdefault(key, value) to set default value for a given key, but is there a way to set default values of all keys to some value after creating a dict ?

Put it another way, I want the dict to return the specified default value for every key I didn't yet set.

Comment: What's this set of "all keys" you are talking about? There's an infinite amount of potential keys, even if you restrict yourself to e.g. strings. Could you give an example?

Comment: you can use get method, `a.get(k[, x]) a[k] if k in a, else x`

Comment: Some help in the inverse direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688453/how-to-fix-default-values-from-a-dictionary-pythonically

Comment: @delnan What I want is to get  a default value for every key I didn't set yet.

Comment: Too lengthy to post here, I describe solutions in this research blog post: https://persagen.com/2020/03/05/python_dictionaries_default_values_immutable_keys.html

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You can replace your old dictionary with a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = {'foo': 123, 'bar': 456}
>>> d['baz']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'baz'
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: -1, d)
>>> d['baz']
-1
```

The "trick" here is that a `defaultdict` can be initialized with another `dict`. This means 
that you preserve the existing values in your normal `dict`:

```
>>> d['foo']
123
```

Comment: Is there any way to get this working with `get` and similar methods or constructs like `in`?

Comment: Isn't just `defaultdict(lambda: -1)` enough? what is the `d` for?

Comment: @yiwei It is there to initialize the `defaultdict` with the values from the existing `dict`. The question said "I want the dict to return the specified default value for every key I didn't yet set." and the way to do this is to create a `defaultdict` initialized with the old `dict`.

Answer (score 15):

Use defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict
a = {} 
a = defaultdict(lambda:0,a)
a["anything"] # => 0
```

This is very useful for case like this,where default values for every key is set as 0:

```
results ={ 'pre-access' : {'count': 4, 'pass_count': 2},'no-access' : {'count': 55, 'pass_count': 19}
for k,v in results.iteritems():
  a['count'] += v['count']
  a['pass_count'] += v['pass_count']
```

Answer (score 7):

In case you actually mean what you seem to ask, I'll provide this alternative answer.

You say you want the dict to *return* a specified value, you do not say you want to *set* that value at the same time, like `defaultdict` does. This will do so:

```
class DictWithDefault(dict):
    def __init__(self, default, **kwargs):
        self.default = default
        super(DictWithDefault, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self:
            return super(DictWithDefault, self).__getitem__(key)
        return self.default
```

Use like this:

```
d = DictWIthDefault(99, x=5, y=3)
print d["x"]   # 5
print d[42]    # 99
42 in d        # False
d[42] = 3
42 in d        # True
```

Alternatively, you can use a standard `dict` like this:

```
d = {3: 9, 4: 2}
default = 99
print d.get(3, default)  # 9
print d.get(42, default) # 99
```

Answer (score 6):

[`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) can do something like that for you.

Example:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {})
>>> d['new'].append(10)
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'new': [10]})
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want:

```
>>> d={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
>>> default_val=99
>>> for k in d:
...     d[k]=default_val
...     
>>> d
{'a': 99, 'b': 99, 'c': 99}
>>> 

>>> d={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d=defaultdict(lambda:99,d)
>>> d
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x03D21630>, {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2})
>>> d[3]
99
```

Answer (score 1):

Not after creating it, no. But you could use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) in the first place, which sets default values when you initialize it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following class. Just change zero to any default value you like. The solution was tested in Python 2.7.

```
class cDefaultDict(dict):
    # dictionary that returns zero for missing keys
    # keys with zero values are not stored

    def __missing__(self,key):
        return 0

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if value==0:
            if key in self:  # returns zero anyway, so no need to store it
                del self[key]
        else:
            dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
```