# Initialize list in a python nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am building a dynamic nested python dictonary as below

```
08-Jul-2016 |Offlines | [value1,value2] 
            |Gobxmls  | [value1,value3,value3,value4] 
            |Bregs    | []
```

During initialization, I am not able to add/append elements in list at the end of this dictionary.
This is how i have created the nested dict:

```
class nested_dict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = type(self)()
        return value

d = nested_dict()
```

I want to initialize it this way (within a loop) without checking everytime if its a null list. Is it possible ?

```
for value in values
    d[date][Offlines].append(value)
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [How to set default value to all keys of a dict object in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9139897)

Comment: `d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))`? And note that you're appending a single-element list into another list, which is possibly not what you want.

Comment: yeah, sorry its just the value not another list. Have edited the code.thanks