# Why does using setdefault on a dictionary in python print it out?

Tags: python, linux, windows, dictionary

I'm on Windows, using the PyCharm IDE's terminal to ssh into a linux server, on that server I'm using python interactively. When I update a dictionary with a value, the terminal outputs the value back to me:

```
>>> x={}
>>> x.setdefault("y",0)
0
```

I can't figure out why this is happening. I've never noticed that behavior before? I also tried to ssh directly with the Windows 10 terminal but the same thing happens, so it's not PyCharm specific.

I just don't want the visual clutter of it throwing a value back at me every time I try to set up a dictionary. What could be making it do this? It's the first time I login through Windows so I feel like this is somehow the culprit?

Comment: [Official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thymine!

This is the expected behavior, as you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)

> **setdefault**(key[, default])
>
> If key is in the dictionary, return its  value. If not, insert key
> with a value of default and return default.  default defaults to None.

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139897/how-to-set-default-value-to-all-keys-of-a-dict-object-in-python) can help you too

Comment: Is there a way to set a default value without having it returned? I can't seem to find one

Comment: assign it to variable c = x.setdefault("y", 0) so c is noting but throwaway variable.

Comment: I edited my answer adding the following 
link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139897/how-to-set-default-value-to-all-keys-of-a-dict-object-in-python

Answer (score 0):

It's not windows specific."setdefault" returns the value of key also you are using python in interactive mode you will get the returned value. you can assign it to variable.